# LocalDate no me deja instanciar

Tags: java

estoy investigando un poco la **Api** de java , quiero crear una clase como esta , pero en vez de usar `GregorianCalendar` tengo que usar `LocalDate`. pero no se como hacerlo, me dijeron que `GregorianCalendar` quedo desactualizada que es conveniente usar `LocalDate`  , alguien me puede decir Porque ? saludos

```
public class Empleado implements Comparable , Jefes {

    private String nombre;
    private double sueldo;
    private Date alta_Contrato;
    private static int idSigiguiente;
    private int id;

    public Empleado(String nom, double sue, int agno, int mes, int dia) {

        nombre = nom;
        sueldo = sue;
        GregorianCalendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar(agno, mes, dia);
        alta_Contrato = calendario.getTime();
        ++idSigiguiente;
        id = idSigiguiente;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A grandes rasgos la API de Calendar no fue bien recibida en la comunidad esto se debió en parte a 2 grades problemas que la comunidad espero que resolviera, pero fallo estrepitosamente:

1. Remplazar la pobre implementación de Java Date para el manejo de fechas, horas y zonas horaria, a lo cual Calendar termino creando una mezcla entre Calendar y Date terminando con una API aún más confusa en muchos caos en la cual no puedes aplicar la lógica y sentido común para saber su uso y en muchos casos no se comportará como esperas.
2. Proporcionar un remplazo para la gran librería de joda-time que entre sus múltiples ventajas es thread safe, mientras que Calendar a pesar de ser una nueva implementación al depender internamente de Date sigue sin ser thread safe.

A continuación, te detallo algunos ejemplos:

1. Java Date no es intuitiva:
   Viendo este ejemplo en el cual se quiere crear un objeto Date con la fecha 25 de diciembre del 2017, a las 8:30 PM. Entonces pensarías que según la lógica esta sería la solución:

   ```
   Date date = new Date(2017, 12, 25, 20, 30);
   // esto seria Fri Jan 25 20:30:00 CET 3918 <- año 3918
   ```

Pero nada mas lejos de la realidad, esta sería la forma correcta :

```
int year = 2017 - 1900;
int month = 12 - 1;
Date date = new Date(year, month, 25, 20, 30);
```

Esto se debe a que enero es 0, entonces diciembre es 11 y Date usa el año 1900 como base o punto cero.

2. Zonas Horarias:
   Hasta Java 8, para especificar las zonas horarias debías ingresar un String como parámetro de la zona horaria en lugar de un Enum, como sabrás los String no poseen validación en tiempo de compilación por lo que cualquier valor que ingreses es correcto, por ejemplo, si intentamos obtener la zona horaria de NewYork:

   TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getInstance("America/NewYork");

En este caso estaría incorrecta porque la forma correcta de escritura es “America/New_York”

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getInstance("America/New_York");
```

Esto nunca sabrás que tienes un error porque al colocar una zona no existente no genera una excepción, por lo que debes tener muy presente la escritura para cualquier zona horario que debas utilizar.

3. Calendar:

Uno pensaría que al ser una nueva implementación corregiría muchos de los fallos de Date pero la verdad solo introdujeron nuevos y en algunos casos mas complejos, por ejemplo el crear un Objeto Calendar para una fecha y zona horaria específica, en este ejemplo Calendar no retornara un error o excepción solo funcionara de una manera errónea pero eso depende de ti y tus pruebas darte cuenta:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(date, zone)
```

Porque la forma correcta de asignar una fecha y zona horaria es la siguiente:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(zone);
cal.setTime(date);
```

Y por ultimo comparemos la API Calendar con la API de LocalTime, recuerda que LocalDate solo maneja fecha y LocalTime maneja fecha y hora, ademas ambas inplementaciones son thread safe:

```
//Sumar 2 horas a la hora actual
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + 2);

LocalTime ahora = LocalTime.now();
LocalTime futuro = ahora.plus(2, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
ó
LocalTime futuro2 = LocalTime.now().plus(2, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
```

Como esto hay muchos mas ejemplo y problemas que te puedes encontrar, lo cual provoco la rápida creación de la API LocalTime y LocalDate prestando más atención a la comunidad para corregir las deficiencias de Calendar y Date.

Para tu ejemplo deberías cambiar el Date por LocalDate:

```
private LocalDate alta_Contrato;
alta_Contrato = LocalDate.of(agno, mes, dia);
```

Si usas Calendar Junio es 5 pero en LocalDate Junio es 6 como debe de ser.

> Estos ejemplo fueron tomados de el blog https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/04/5-reasons-why-javas-old-date-and-Calendar-API-bad.html del cual realizo una traducción bajo mi propia opinión.